# Monit not send alert message and give error ' Alert handler failed, retry scheduled for next cycle'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, sendmail, monit

We use monit to monitor server like (space usage ,cpu usage etc). When resource limit exceed , monit not deliver alert message and give following error- Sendmail error: 534-5.7.9 Please log in with your web browser and then try again.

Alert handler failed, retry scheduled for next cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Your SMTP server is rejecting monit connection, and doesn`t send mail

```
Sendmail error: 534-5.7.9 Please log in with your web browser and then try again.
```

You should configure a SMTP relay server that trusts you and don't ask you for login from the server IP

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Problem was, as Raul commented before, the SMTP. In my case, the problem was the Postfix.

Because I just wanted SMTP to send the emails from monit it was ok for me to remove default Postfix installation and installed again:

**# apt-get remove --purge postftix**

**# apt-get install postfix**

then I choose "Internet Site"

Automatically Monit was able to send mails, no more errors in var/log/monit.log

Hope it helps